# vbscript not working, end of statement error or missing )

Tags: powershell, vbscript

im trying to make a vbscript that would list all contents in dir and read through each file extracting the data to manipulate and run a powershell script using this data as arguments. i found the following to start off with but it does not work. can somebody help?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' make a reference to a directory
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\")
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

    'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each dra In diar1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just do the whole thing in Powershell?

Comment: For what it is worth, what you posted is VB.Net, not VBScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBScript was very similar to VB, but it was a long time since I used VB last time...

AFAIR ListBox1.Items.Add() expects and Item or a string as a parameter, NOT a FileInfo object
Try to use 
ListBox1.Items.Add(FileInfo.FullName)